# string replace with hashtable creats an object full of arrays

Tags: powershell, replace, hashtable

I try to replace a string inside of a object.
However since I managed to do it, I have the behaviour that every single object is now an array.

my Code so far

```
$hash = @{ 
    SRVNamex = "place1"
    SRVNamey = "place2"
    SRVNamez = "place3"
}

$printers = Get-ADObject -LDAPFilter "(objectCategory=printQueue)" -Properties * | select  printerName, shortServerName, location, description, uncname, drivername #| Format-Table -Property *

$f = foreach($printer in $printers){
    $pn = $printer.shortServerName
    if($hash.ContainsKey($pn)){
        $printer = $printer -replace $pn, $hash[$pn]
    }else{
    }
    $printer
}
```

My Input looks like this

```
printerName   shortServerName    location      description       uncname          drivername                          
HPRT04        SRVNamex           xxxx          xxxxx             xxxxx            Datamax-O'Neil
P11           SRVNamey           EDV           xxx               xxxx             Zebra
```

Output should look like this:

```
printerName   shortServerName    location      description       uncname          drivername                          
HPRT04        palce1             xxxx          xxxxx             xxxxx            Datamax-O'Neil
P11           palce2             EDV           xxx               xxxx             Zebra
```

Comment: `$printer = $printer -replace $pn, $hash[$pn]` --> `$printer.shortServerName = $hash[$pn]`

Comment: Thank you very much, who would have thougth it would be such a tiny missthinking.

Can't mark it as asnwered.

Comment: Because this is just a simple and easy to make mistake, I don't think it qualifies for a real answer, that's why I simply did the comment. Glad to have helped!